# Displaying multiple images on social feed in grid style

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display multiple images on the social feed list view of my Android app, something similar to how the Facebook Android app does.
Refer image below:

[image]

The maximum number of images to be display in a post is 3. 
For multiple images, I want the images to be dynamically arranged/resized as per their sizes in a grid type format as shown.

I've tried adjusting 3 ImageViews inside a LinearLayout by specifying layout_weight but does not work.
Any kind of help/advice or sample code is really appreciated!!! orz

Comment: Hey @Vishy If you have any soluion for that plz sugest me how to do this.

Comment: Well I finally implemented this using a GridView, using custom ImageViews.  I adjusted the height and width of my images dynamically by creating a Custom ImageView class and setting the height and width ration from java. I set a limit of maximum 3 images  to be displayed on the feed at any time. For more than 3 images, i placed a button below the images which took the user to a different activity displaying all the images. For less than 3 images, i made the ImageViews visible/ invisible and adjusted accordingly

Comment: Any code for how to parse Facebook feeds.

Comment: Ah no, sorry I wasn't working with Facebook feeds. The images in the question above were used just an an example for the multi-Image layout. In my case I was parsing JSON data which had image Urls, then I downloaded images from those Urls in a different thread

Comment: How you organize your images as the picture 2 in each row, i see if an image with the largest height will take column 1 with 2 rows, and the rest of 2 just only column 2 and each takes one row. I really thanks if you share me any code or some idea to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I have done this please check may be you get your answer
 This is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now i have done pro-grammatically the setting of images 
which is

```
public class ImageShow extends Activity {
            ImageView img1,img2,img3,img4;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.image_dsgn);
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int width = size.x;
                int sst=width-20;
                Log.d("Width is",String.valueOf(sst));
                Log.d("Width is",String.valueOf(width));
                int i=3;
                FrameLayout frameLayout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.imgframe);
                if(i==1)
                {    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView.setPadding(0,5,0,0);
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width,400));
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView);
                }
                if(i==2)
                {    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView.setPadding(0,5,0,0);
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width/2,
                            400));
                    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView1.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width/2,
                            400));
                    imageView1.setX(width/2);
                    imageView1.setPadding(5,5,0,0);
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView);
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView1);
                }
                if(i==3)
                {
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView.setPadding(0,5,0,0);
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width/2,
                            400));
                    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView1.setX(width/2);
                    imageView1.setPadding(5,5,0,0);
                    imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView1.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width/2,
                            200));
                    ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView2.setX(width/2);
                    imageView2.setY(200);
                    imageView2.setPadding(5,5,0,0);
                    imageView2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView2.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width/2,
                            200));
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView);
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView1);
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView2);
                }
                if(i==4)
                {
                    //x=0,y=0
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView.setPadding(0,5,0,0);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(sst/2,400));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    //x=200,y==0
                    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView1.setX(sst/2);
                    imageView1.setPadding(2,5,0,0);
                    imageView1.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(sst/2,400/3));
                    imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                    ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView2.setX(sst/2);
                    imageView2.setY(400/3);
                    imageView2.setPadding(2,5,0,0);
                    imageView2.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(sst/2,400/3));
                    imageView2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                    ImageView imageView3= new ImageView(this);
                    imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
                    imageView3.setX(sst/2);
                    imageView3.setY((400/3+400/3));
                    imageView3.setPadding(2,5,0,0);
                    imageView3.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(sst/2,400/3));
                    imageView3.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


                    TextView textView=new TextView(this);
                    textView.setText("+ 6");
                    textView.setX(sst/2);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView.setY(400/3+400/3);
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    textView.setTextSize(20);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(sst/2,400/3));
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView);
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView1);
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView2);
                    frameLayout.addView(imageView3);
                    frameLayout.addView(textView);
                }

            }
        }
```